# How to send notification from one android application to other android application?

Tags: java, android, android-push-notification

I've created **two different** android applications, one for the **admin panel** which has only one user itself, and the other one which will be **installed on other android devices**. As the admin *adds notifications* in his application, *all users will get the notifications*. what should I do? How to implement this?

Answer (score 1):

You sound a beginner so I will explain in simple words first.

- You need a server side script which can trigger the notification sending code, If you are running `PHP` as your server side language then you can use my code below.
- Then you need your **User** application to subscribed to a topic. A topic is just a custom string. You will use this topic string to send notification to specific user or user groups.
- From your **Admin** application you need to call that `PHP` script on server that can trigger notification. I assume you already know how to call a `PHP` script, It's same as calling the normal `API` to do operations in `Database`.

Having known the process flow you need to follow below steps.

- Follow [this](https://firebase.google.com/docs/cloud-messaging/android/client) tutorial to start a `Firebase` project and acquire `FCM Notification` functionality. **Get firebase api key from the console.**
- In your **User** application subscribe to a topic using the code below. Put this code in the `onCreate` method of the `Activity` after user logs into app. Unsubscribe the topic if you want user to stop receiving notifications.

  ```
  FirebaseMessaging.getInstance().subscribeToTopic("your topic name here"); //to subscribe
  FirebaseMessaging.getInstance().unsubscribeFromTopic("your topic name here"); //to unsubscribe
  ```
- Put this code in a `PHP` file, you need to call this to trigger notification.

  ```
   define('FIREBASE_API_KEY', 'your firebase api key');

   $title = "this will display as notification title";
   $body = "subject of notification";
   $topic = "your topic name";

   $message["title"] = $title;
   $message["body"] = $body;

    $fields = array(
         'to' => '/topics/'.$topic,
         'notification' => $message,
     );
     // Set POST variables
     $url = 'https://fcm.googleapis.com/fcm/send';

     $headers = array(
         'Authorization: key=' . FIREBASE_API_KEY,
         'Content-Type: application/json'
     );
     // Open connection
     $ch = curl_init();

     // Set the url, number of POST vars, POST data
     curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $url);

     curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, true);
     curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, $headers);
     curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);

     // Disabling SSL Certificate support temporarly
     curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, false);

     curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, json_encode($fields));

     // Execute post
   $result='';
   if($title!=null){ 
     $result = curl_exec($ch);

       if ($result === FALSE) {
           die('Curl failed: ' . curl_error($ch));
       }
   }  
     // Close connection
     curl_close($ch);
  ```
- Now call this `PHP` script from your **Admin** application. You can pass parameters according to your needs. You will be able to get a notification in your **User** app.

You can customize the notification in your `Android` code, like playing a specific sound. For that you need to follow the official document guide I linked above.

Answer (score 0):

Use firebase FCM for sending the push notifications to android devices. Here you will find lot of options. https://firebase.google.com/docs/cloud-messaging

Comment: But can my other application be able to get those notifications?